# Change or turn off the default rss in Piranha cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rss, piranha-cms

I have created a website with piranha CMS and a custom routing class. The links in the RSS flow is now broken. Can I change or turn off the default RSS solution?

I tried to solve this problem by creating a controller that returns an RSS feed with the correct links. In RouteConfig I added this map route:

```
routes.MapRoute (
                 name: "rss"
                 url: 'rss'
                 defaults: new {controller = "RSS", action = "Index"},
                 namespaces: new [] {"onceuponatime.Controllers"}
             );
```

But when `http://mywebsite.com/rss` called, it's still the default solution that is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application starts a number of default request handlers are registered, among them the [RssHandler](https://github.com/tidyui/Piranha/blob/master/Piranha/Application.cs#L160). You can disable it by adding the following statement in you startup code, like Global.asax.cs:

```
Piranha.Application.Current.Handlers.Remove("RSS") ;
```

This will disable the default implementation and let you handle calls for /rss yourself.